# Right click on a menu item and show options

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, right-click, contextmenu

I have menu ServerList, I am adding the menuItems dynamically using C# code. It reads the servers list from file and populate the menu items. I have added the right click options for each server. Edit & Delete.

All this is working fine. the problem is how do I read actual server name when Edit/Detele is clicked.

Here is the code

```
       public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadMenuItems();
    }

    //Currently static values, but reads from file. later
    private void LoadMenuItems()
    {
        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
        item2.Header = "Server1";
        AddContextMenu(item2);

        MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem();
        item3.Header = "Server2";
        AddContextMenu(item3);

        ActualMenu.Items.Add(item2);
        ActualMenu.Items.Add(item3);
    }

    private void AddContextMenu(MenuItem item)
    {
        MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
        item1.Header = "Edit";            
        item1.Click += item_Click;

        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
        item2.Header = "Detlete";
        item2.Click += item_Click;

       ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.Items.Add(item1);
        menu.Items.Add(item2);

        item.ContextMenu = menu;
    }

    void item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        string header = item.Header.ToString();            
    }
```

Comment: I guess your item_Click code is wrong, because that would have been my first guess to ask the sender. Have you tried the RoutedEventArgs argument on the item_click handler? There should be a Source property which is afair the clicked menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this use `PlacementTarget`.

```
 private void AddContextMenu(MenuItem item)
 {
    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
    ....
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    ....
    menu.PlacementTarget = item;   /// 'Connects' context menu to source menu item.
    item.ContextMenu = menu;
 } 

 void item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
    string header
       = ((MenuItem)((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).PlacementTarget).Header;
 }
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Header of a MenuItem uses a TextBlock to display content. So, in this case you need to convert the Header to a TextBox, then look at the Text property.

For example,

```
void item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    string servername =  ((sender as MenuItem).Header as TextBlock).Text;
}
```